# Кириллица в консоли C

Tags: c

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru-RU");
wchar_t s[80];
_getws_s(s, _countof(s));
wprintf(L"ТЕКСТ\n%s\n", s);
```

В итоге слово "ТЕКСТ" будет выведено верно, а та строка, которую мы введём, отобразится некорректно.
Почему `wprintf` справляется с выводом кириллицы, а `_getws_s` не справляется с вводом?

Comment: Какая ОС? (ну а по сути у вас кодировка файла и терминала отличаются).

Comment: Windows. А при чём тут кодировка файла?

Comment: *В итоге слово "ТЕКСТ" будет выведено верно, ...*

Comment: Так выведено на терминал.

Comment: Таки откуда? Вот.

Comment: Ввод в буфер терминала.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду что при выводе используется одна кодировка, а при ввода другая? Почему `setlocale` не устанавливает одну и ту же кодировку на ввод и вывод тогда?

Comment: У вас есть несколько сущностей, и все здесь смешались. Первое — кодировка файла. Текст, закодированный в файле, будет в этой кодировке. Второе — локаль, в которой работает ваш терминал. Она определяет кодировку того, что вводится и выводится. Третье — локаль процесса, то есть вашей программы. Она определяется теми настройками, которые заданы либо системой, либо каким-то образом (например, вызовом `setlocale()`) установлены изнутри. Разберитесь с этим всем вначале.

Comment: Это всё понятно. Вопрос даже не в том, как сделать код рабочим. Вопрос как работает `_getws` так, что в `s` не та кодировка получается. Можете сказать почему не та кодировка?

Comment: Даже наверное не в кодировке и дело. Потому что они должны совпадать. Я заметил, что коды символов при вводе сдвигаются влево на 16. При выводе этого нет.

Comment: На 16 чего? Можете пример привести?

Comment: Кстати, документация-то читана? https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/blob/master/docs/c-runtime-library/reference/gets-s-getws-s.md

Comment: _"Можете пример привести?"_ - Вводится символ с кодом 0x100, но в буфере оказывается другой символ с кодом 0x90. _"Кстати, документация-то читана?"_ - Да.